# Is there a official release date for RWBY volume 5 on DVD?

Tags: rwby

I already have every other volume of RWBY on DVD.  And someone who works at Walmart told me that volume 5 would be released sometime in January but here it is February already and I can't find it anywhere I know it's supposed to have been released but I don't think it has yet. Can anyone help?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be much information.

Comment: http://collider.com/rwby-volume-5-release-date/ - October 2017, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to break it to you but there is no current release date for it on DVD/Bluray all google searches say theatrical release date which is in October http://variety.com/2017/digital/news/rwby-volume-5-premiere-date-theatrical-1202560584/
I understand cause I want it too but I think we have to wait a little longer Rooster Teeth hasn't put out anything else. Hope this answer satisfies.

Comment: Another thing is I think it might be released on DVD and Bluray in October but like I said Rooster Teeth hasn't said so it's not known.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually order it now at [Best Buy](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/rwby-vol-5-blu-ray/6221408.p?skuId=6221408) but according to the page it won't be released until `06/05/2018` but it is available now for pre-order if you want.

Comment: I think the soundtrack for Volume 5 is available too js

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! This is a nice sourced first answer.

Answer (score 0):

RWBY Volume 5 is available for preorder from Walmart, Target and other stores now but it won't arrive in stores until June 7 so that's the official release date June 7 of 2018.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! Do you have any evidence to back up your claim?